# d3.json - how to replace URL with object/dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

New to d3.  Creating a sankey diagram.  Found a sample that uses an external .json file. The sample uses d3.v3.  I know that is old, but I have a tree that also uses that version, so I would prefer to just load one d3 version.  The sankey works fine, but I want to replace the static json will with dynamic data pulled from a database.  I would load the page, query the database, retrieve my data, and format it as an array of objects, passing the array to the sankey code.

Starting with small changes, I have copied the contents of the json file and inserted it into my page.

```
var MYDATA = {
"links": [
{"source":"Agricultural Energy Use","target":"Carbon Dioxide","value":"1.4"},
{"source":"Agriculture","target":"Agriculture Soils","value":"5.2"},
{"source":"Agriculture","target":"Livestock and Manure","value":"5.4"},
{"source":"Agriculture","target":"Other Agriculture","value":"1.7"},
...
};
```

The relevant sankey code - where the file is loaded - is

```
d3.json("#APP_FILES#sankeygreenhouse.json", function(error, graph) {
    var nodeMap = {};
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
    graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
      return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value
      };
    });
```

I am trying to change this to use MYDATA instead of '#APP_FILES#sankeygreenhouse.json'
I have tried changing this line to

```
d3.json(MYDATA, function(error, graph) {
```

but this just gives a 404 error.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3.json loads a file and puts it into an object (in the above case, `graph`). By declaring it in an object, you're skipping that step, and putting it in `MYDATA`. You can just directly assign `graph` to `MYDATA` like so:

Change:

```
d3.json(MYDATA, function(error, graph) {
    var nodeMap = {};
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
    graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
      return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value
      };
    });
//...
})
```

to

```
var nodeMap = {};
var graph = MYDATA;
// or if you want to make a copy:
// var graph = structuredClone(MYDATA);

graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
   return {
    source: nodeMap[x.source],
    target: nodeMap[x.target],
    value: x.value
   };
});
```